# reference nuspec file when creating nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am working with creating a nuget package for my class library. I would like to share the one nuspec file for multiple projects. I have the nuspec file in a central location. Is it possible to reference this when creating the package for the class library?

Answer (score -1):

Doing this out-of-the-box will not work, probably. Check http://kamranicus.com/Blog/Posts/32/using-nuspec-inheritance-to-reduce-nuget-maintenan .